# How can I change the value of a matrix uniform in an OpenGL vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm new at OpenGL. I have a uniform transform matrix in a vertex shader file. I want to modify the matrix by individually assigning each values in the matrix. How can I do that in C++?

I learned that we have to get location variable by using `glGetUniformLocation` but I am not sure how to access and modify index *n* with it with `glUniform`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the uniform's location:

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "uniform name");
```

Once you have the location you can send the entire value of the matrix via [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glUniform.xml):

```
const GLFloat matrix[] = { ...16 values of the matrix here... };
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
```

Thus, to change a single element, change it in the CPU-side representation of the matrix (for example, set `matrix[4] = 1.0f`) and re-send the entire matrix uniform, leaving the rest of the elements unchanged.

If, for some reason, you no longer have a CPU-side copy of the matrix value, you can use [`glGetUniformfv`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetUniform.xml) to query the current value of a uniform based on its location. Note that you should generally keep a CPU-side copy of the matrix around because modifying it and sending it via `glUniformMatrix4fv` alone is going to be faster than first querying it via `glGetUniformfv`, modifying the queried data, and resending it.

(You cannot directly query and modify a single element of a matrix via OpenGL, you can only query and send the 16 elements all at once; you can modify a single element of the 16-element array on the CPU however.)

Answer (score 0):

using glUniformMatrix4fv:

```
float[16] matrix = {/*16 individual values*/};

glUniformMatrix4fv(location​, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix ​);
```

this will overwrite all 16 values, if you want to keep the old ones you can keep them yourself or query them with [`glGetUniform`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetUniform)